# How convert Linq result into json and use that json in mvc3 view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

My models are:

```
public class FloorNames
{
    [Key]
    public int FloorId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "FloorName required")]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string FloorName { get; set; }
}

public class RoomDetails
{

    [Key]
    public int RoomDetailsId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "RoomNo required")]        
    public int RoomNo { get; set; }

    public int RoomTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Adult required")]

    public int Adult { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Child required")]

     public int Child { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Child required")]

     public bool ExtraBed { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "ExtraBedNumbers required")]        
     public int ExtraBedNumbers { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "RoomFloorNo required")]        
    public int FloorId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "RoomRate required")]        
     public int RoomRate { get; set; }

    public virtual RoomType RoomType { get; set; }
    public virtual FloorNames FloorNames { get; set; }
}


public class RoomType
{
    public int RoomTypeId { get; set; }
    public string RoomTypeName { get; set; }

}
```

The controller class is:

```
public class ReceptionController : Controller
{

    private MVCLodgeEntities db = new MVCLodgeEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()

    {
        var roomdetails = db.RoomDetails.Include(r => r.RoomType).Include(r => r.FloorNames);

        roomdetails = roomdetails.OrderByDescending(s => s.FloorNames.FloorName);


        return View(roomdetails.ToList());
    }


}
```

And in my view i have written the code:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcLodge.Models.RoomDetails>

@{

    ViewBag.Title = "Index";

 }

<h2>Reception</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")

</p>

<table>

@{

    var fn="";

    var i = 1;

}  

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    if (i == 1)
    {

       fn = "II Floor";
    }

    if (fn == item.FloorNames.FloorName)
    {

        fn = item.FloorNames.FloorName;

        <td>

             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoomNo)- @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoomType.RoomTypeName)

             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Adult) -  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Child)-@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FloorNames.FloorName)

             <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Store", new { id = item.RoomNo})"> 

                 <img alt="@item.RoomNo" src="../../Images/abs.png" />

             </a> 

        </td>

    }

    else
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoomNo)- @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoomType.RoomTypeName)<br/>

                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Adult) -  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Child)-@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FloorNames.FloorName)<br/>

               <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Store", new { id = item.RoomNo})"> 

                   <img alt="@item.RoomNo" src="../../Images/abs.png" /> 

              </a> 

           </td>

      </tr>

    }

}

</table>
```

My Output is similar to this:

```
101 Ac III Floor

102 AC II Floor    103 AC II Floor

104 AC IFloor

105 AC IFloor
```

But i want to display all the I floor in same row and vice veersa like

```
101 Ac III Floor

102 AC II Floor    103 AC II Floor

104 AC I Floor      105 AC I Floor
```

please help me...

Comment: At first sight you are not assigning `fn = item.FloorNames.FloorName;` on the `else` and you are not handling correctly the `<tr>` in the foreach

Comment: Thankyou for your reply..But still i have the problem